# Running Bokeh with interactive Widgets

Tags: python, widget, bokeh

I would like to run a Bokeh App with an interactive Widget but cannot get it fully working.

My code `demo.py`:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Dropdown
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers

# Data
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': flowers['sepal_length'], 'y': flowers['sepal_width'], 'species': flowers['species']})

# Source
SPECIES = 'versicolor'
source = ColumnDataSource(df.loc[df.species == SPECIES])

# Create plots and widgets
plot = figure()
plot.circle(x= 'x', y='y', source=source)

menu = [("setosa", "setosa"), ("versicolor", "versicolor"), None, ("virginica", "virginica")]
dropdown = Dropdown(label="Dropdown species", button_type="warning", menu=menu)

# Add callback to widgets
def callback(attr, old, new):
    SPECIES = dropdown.value
    source.data=ColumnDataSource(df.loc[df.species == SPECIES])
dropdown.on_change('value', callback)

# Arrange plots and widgets in layouts
layout = column(dropdown, plot)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

When I run this app from the command line interface with `bokeh serve --show demo.py`, it returns an HTML-page with a plot. The dropdown seems to work, but the plot does not change when a value is selected from the dropdown.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not assigning the correct value to `source.data`. The value needs to be a regular Python dict that maps column names to lists/arrays of data. There are a variety of ways to do that demonstrated in the docs and examples, but one good way is to use the `from_df` class method of CDS to generate the right kind of dict:

```
source.data = ColumnDataSource.from_df(df.loc[df.species == SPECIES])
```

That line makes your code work as expected.

As an FYI, your code generates an error in the server console output (as should be expected):

> error handling message Message 'PATCH-DOC' (revision 1): ValueError("expected an element of ColumnData(String, Seq(Any)), got ColumnDataSource(id='44e09b5e-133b-4c1b-987b-cbf80b803401', ...)",)

As a gentle suggestion, it's always a good idea to include such errors in SO questions.

Comment: Thanks for your help and gentle suggestion ;-)